# Is there a compile on demand option for an ASP.NET Web Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net, compiler-construction, vs-web-application-project

I just started working with an ASP.NET application that has been converted from a VB.NET web site to a C# web project and I am finding that my development time is significantly longer using C# than VB.NET.

When I am editing a simple line of code in an C# code behind file, I have to manually recompile the entire site just to see the result of the change. In with the web site, I could edit a code behind file and then execute it in the browser to see the result of the change without doing a compile (or alternatively, right-click and choose compile page).

Is there an option somewhere to compile JUST THE ONE PAGE? If not, is there something that can be done (other than getting more hardware or converting the project back to web site) to speed up the development/debugging process?

**Clarification**

In a ASP.NET (VB) Web Site project I can make an edit in code-behind, click the save button, then open up a browser and navigate to the page to instantly see the change (or at least within 5 seconds). In a Web Application Project in ASP.NET (C#), I am finding I have to compile the entire web site to view the live change in a browser (a process that takes upwards of 2 minutes).

Comment: Is this a difference between ASP.NET Web Site and Web Application projects, I wonder?

Comment: @abatishchev Which makes it a language-independent issue, therefore the question needs rephrasing.

Comment: @tomfanning: Sure, it's a general .NET/ASP.NET question, just need to get the clarification from OP

Comment: VB.NET - I updated my question.

Comment: @tomfanning: Please post tour proposition as an answer.

Comment: How do I tell whether this is a web application or web project? The project is open source: https://github.com/mmcconnell1618/MerchantTribe

Comment: @NightOwl888: If a web project contains .Designer.cs files - then it's a web app project, otherwise - web site project.

Comment: Did you try replacing the CodeBehind attribute of one of your most simple .aspx page with Codefile ? It should make the .aspx.cs recompile on demand.

Answer (score 3):

Your .aspx and .ascx should reference their codehind files through CodeFile instead of CodeBehind. Then the codebehin will be compiled on demand.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" CodeFile="myPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="myPage" %>
```

instead of

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="true" CodeBehind="myPage.aspx.cs" Inherits="myPage" %>
```

There are some drawbacks though :

- CodeBehind pages can not use CodeFile controls (but codefile pages can use any kind of controls)
- referencing codefile controls is a bit more complicated
- you will lose sync with the .designer.cs and have to reswitch to codebehind for a second to resync.

On the long run, CodeFile will save you a lot of time.

Comment: I think you're [wrong](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ydy4x04a.aspx). You can use CodeBehind in WebApp, and CodeFile in WebSite. And [can't mix that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx).

Comment: @abatishchev I'm sure I am right concerning web applications as I work daily on projects mixing CodeFile and CodeBehind. I just tested it on a brand new ASP.NET Web application created with vs2010, running on IIS 7.5, changing the codebehind of the default page to codefile. It works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your solution at any time by pressing `Ctrl + Shift + B`.

Right-click and `Exclude` any projects/folders/files you don't want to include.

**EDIT**: A Web Application Project has to be built in its entirety, but Visual Studio only builds those files which have changed so this shouldn't be too slow for you.

In a Web ***Site*** Project, Visual Studio completely compiles Web site projects whenever you run or debug any page by default - **but** - you can change the build project option to compile only the current page on run or debug.

[image]

Comment: When you say Exclude, do you mean exclude the files from the project?

Comment: When I posted this question, I didn't realize the project had also been converted to a web project in addition to being converted to C#. I rephrased the question. You mentioned that a web project must be compiled entirely - is there any way around this?

Comment: @NightOwl888 Not that I know of (but that's not to say there isn't). The best I can do is to point you to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983464.aspx)